# [Layout].Children.Clear() or Remove() gives error in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I use an AbsoluteLayout in my form as the Content of a ContentView. I add another ContentView in AbsoluteLayout and when I want to clear the children or remove any children I get ObjectReferenceException. Is this a known bug of Xamarin Forms? Here is the code that gives the error:

```
var scrollView = new ScrollView ();
absoluteLayout.Children.Insert (0, scrollView);
absoluteLayout.Children.RemoveAt (0);
```

I used Insert/RemoveAt in the code but the error happens when I also use Add/Clear.

Comment: You can Check any known Xamarin.Forms bugs [Here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&list_id=190467&order=Importance&product=Forms&query_format=specific)

Comment: This error occur when you have added event at your children controller and there is some thing null object reference.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't use Children property of a Scroll View, I have used the Content and to remove the previous layout I use:

```
StackLayout mainView = new StackLayout();

ScrollView scView = new ScrollView{
    Content = mainView,
};
```

So for instance what you want to wipe out is the mainView not the ScrollView I suppose.